# opposite of insert into - removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I am very new to Sql, so bear with me. I have run a query the following query:

```
INSERT INTO adhoc_dt.`table` (id, name) VALUES(53098974, 'John');
```

however, by accident I run it twice. I would like to remove the duplicate. How can that be done?

I tried

```
 INSERT INTO adhoc_dt.`table` (id, name) VALUES(53098974, 'John');
```

but get an error:

> SQL ERROR  [1064][42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near

Comment: What's the exact error? Also, if id is unique key or primary key you need not worry about having duplicates.

Comment: SQL only has 3 ways to action a table INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE but you have a problem deleting if you have no way of uniquely identifying rows (something an auto_increment id or timestamp is useful for). Do you have a unique row identifier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table name include special char of reserved word then you should enclose the table name with backticks:

```
 `table`
```

But looking to your question, the table name seems:

```
`adhoc_dt.`table`
```

In this case, the correct syntax for delete is:

```
DELETE FROM  adhoc_dt.`table`
WHERE id =  53098974 AND name =  'JOHN'
```

but in this way you delete all the rows with:

```
 id =  53098974 AND name =  'JOHN'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow steps

- truncate table
- apply unique constraint on ID
- run insert script

Comment: And how do we do that? As this generates more questions as it seams this does not answer anything?